# Aplicativo não instala. Ionic 2 e One Signal

Tags: android, ionic2, api

Bom dia. Estou gerando a apk via --prod --release, consigo gerar a apk, consigo assinar mas quando coloco em um aplicativo real o app não instala. Isso começou a acontecer quando comecei a usar o one signal. No comando run android o aplicativo funcioona normalmente.

Comment: E qual é o erro? Alguma mensagem no console? Existem inúmeras coisas que podem acontecer, sem saber mais, recomendaria remover a plataforma android e adicionar novamente `ionic cordova platform remove android`, depois `ionic cordova platform add android`

Comment: Na verdade ele não gera erro, ele simplesmente não instala. Mas eu resolvi o problema removendo a plataforma android e adicionando novamente. Existe outro erro na plataforma IOS que da fala que a plataforma não existe, encontrei a forma de arrumar removendo do config.xml a tag <engine> referente ao IOS.